# What is the name of this traditional Chinese character font?

Tags: traditional-characters

The image below is from a book I bought while in Hong Kong (ISBN 957-14-4160-0. It's an edition of a work in classical Chinese, with an ancient commentary in classical Chinese, and a modern commentary in mandarin. The book is [published in Taiwan](http://www.sanmin.com.tw).

I have looked all through the book for any mention of the typefaces used to typeset the book, and have not found one.

[image: what nice characters]

I am basically in love with the typeface used for the mandarin commentary. I have never seen anything quite like it. The characters are rectangular, and usually 'top-heavy'. Since some of them are quite similar to handwritten forms I have developed over time, I would like to be able to use the font on my computer.

Can anyone help identify it?

Comment: According to this thread ( http://www.pkucn.com/viewthread.php?tid=243063 ), this font is developed by San Min Book Co., Ltd. for their own publications only, and may not be available for selling.

Answer (score 1):

How about [axisstd-extralight](http://www.zhaozi.cn/fonts/china/riben/2010-11-18/21993.html)?

Comment: It's probably close enough, but not quite identical. If you try a sample character like 的, you'll see that the left side has two strokes that cross below the bottom stroke in the font that magnetar posted, but only one stroke does in axisstd-extralight.

Answer (score 1):

This one is also very similar:

[金梅個性钢笔字体](http://font.chinaz.com/1028151550.htm)